# Is there away to make a popup do a request to display extra information

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make an information board that when user press for more information, it will do a get /:id to the backend where it will grab the data and display it in the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
const onClickHandler= async () => {
  const res = await fetch(endpoint);
  const data = await res.json();
  setData(data)
}
```

But using try catch and the rest of things to validate a successful req.

Comment: That is a pretty good idea.

Comment: I hope it works for you :)